# ESTA expires the day after I fly to the US. Is this OK?

Tags: usa, esta, visa-expiration

I have an ESTA which will expire on the 27th of September.  As I fly to the US on the 26th of September, do I get a new one? I am an Australian resident.

Comment: Well it won't be valid for the duration of your trip, so yes? Am I missing something from your question?

Comment: @MarkMayo ESTA need not be valid for the duration of the trip.  It only needs to be valid on entry.

Comment: @phoog wow, today I learned!

Comment: @MarkMayo it is yet another way in which the thing-that-is-not-a-visa is nonetheless similar to a visa.

Comment: Yes, the USA is such that the visa or ESTA allows you to request entry and the admission stamp in your passport shows how long can you stay. Typically this is a date (but can be years ahead for H visas) or have an annotation to say F1 D/S or J1 D/S meaning as long as you are in status (enrolled in your study program etc).

Comment: @chx ESTA _doesn't_ allow you to request entry; it allows you to get on a plane. You request entry under the Visa Waiver Program.

Comment: I would worry that something might go wrong, and by the time the airline had found a replacement plane or switched your ticket, you'd be denied boarding. (I was once on a flight which left fourteen hours late, the a.m. after the scheduled p.m. departure).

Comment: Mark I will arive in the US on the 26 th

Comment: @chx there are other D/S classes aside from F-1 and J-1.  The critical bit is the "until" notation (as labeled on the stamp); as long as this says D/S, the admission is for duration of status.

Answer (score 11):

It is [ok if your ESTA application expires during your trip](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1126/~/esta---length-of-approval), but it must be valid when you enter the US. Depending on exactly when your flight arrives in the US, that may or may not be a problem.

Since it lasts for two years and costs $14 USD, I would find it worthwhile to apply for a new one before your trip, for peace of mind and to ensure you won't have any problems if your flights are delayed.

You can [confirm the validity of your ESTA](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e3s1) online and [apply for a new one](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e4s1) if needed.

Note that the validity of your ESTA only covers when you are allowed to enter the US; it has nothing to do with how long you are allowed to stay in the US. Each visit under the Visa Waiver Program is normally limited to 90 days and is subject to all [the usual rules](https://au.usembassy.gov/visas/visa-waiver-program/).

Comment: There is a slight risk of applying for an ESTA even though it isn't strictly needed. What happens if it's refused?

Comment: "Depending on exactly when your flight arrives in the US, that may or may not be a problem." It would have to arrive on the 28th for it to be a problem.

Comment: Well you never know what happens in terms of rescheduling, cancellations, etc. I would apply for a new ESTA just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @user102008 And it might, in fact, arrive on the 28th. Who knows what flights might get canceled or delayed.